# Creating activity with 3 fragments

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-studio

I currently have an application for my phone which uses a tab navigation actionbar to navigate between three fragments.

I now want to create a tablet equivalent of this app, but instead of using the actionbar, I want the three fragments living next to each other. So each fragment would fill up 1/3th of the screen.

The problem is, I can't figure out how to approach this. I've thought of using the Design part of Android Studio to create placeholders, then use the `onCreate()` method to fill those placeholders by inflating the fragments in it. But I still have no idea on how to approach this.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make 3 placeholders each taking one third of the screen and then fill them in with fragments. Of course you have to make those only in layout for tablets.

```
Fragment fragment1 = new FirstFragment();
Fragment fragment2 = new SecondFragment();
Fragment fragment3 = new ThirdFragment();

getSupportFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.placeholder1, fragment1)
    .replace(R.id.placeholder2, fragment2)
    .replace(R.id.placeholder3, fragment3)
    .commit();
```

EDIT: Example of layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/placeholder1"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/placeholder2"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/placeholder3"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I thought of as well. I currently have a 'splash'-screen that decides if the device is tablet or phone, and boots the appriopiate activity with it. You say you use placeholders, but what are those placeholders? Say I use `activity_main_tablet.xml` for this, which items should go in there?

Comment: Oh. You were faster. :D

Comment: `getSupportFragmentManager` is afaik only used in a compatibility library context with a support-library-FragmentActivity isn't it?

Comment: I added layout example with placeholders. @MABVT Yes, if you're not using support libraries you just use getFragmentManager()

Comment: Thanks for the layout! That's the one I was looking for. You and @MABVT thanks for the code as well, I'll get playing right away.

Answer (score 1):

Your idea to use onCreate() is good.

Basically all you need is a container of type ViewGroup foreach of your fragments and then use FragmentTransactions to add them accordingly.

Consider this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.yourlayout);         

    // Create fragments
    Fragment f0 = new Fragment0();
    Fragment f1 = new Fragment1();
    Fragment f2 = new Fragment2();

    // Add fragments
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.add(R.id.container0, f0);
    ft.add(R.id.container1, f1);
    ft.add(R.id.container2, f2);
    ft.commit();
}
```

See this for more examples and background information: http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2013/04/android-fragment-transaction.html