# How to split the tablet screen in 2 or three parts in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, tablet

I want to create the application which have the design in image below. how to create the design as shown in image. I have no idea about dividing tablet screen in such a way.

[image: Design I want to create.]

Comment: you can use 3 fragment in 1 LinearLayout by sumWeight.
check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26605161/4797289)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#ff00"
    />

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#000000"
    />

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#009dff"
    />
```

add anything in 3 fragments and then replace frame layouts with them using.

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.layout.layout_name, new Fragment_name());
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use your application on several screen sizes, you will have to go through the [fragments](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html).

- In landscape and big screen, your layout contains 3 fragments : menu, list and description.
- In portrait, your layout contains 2 fragments, menu in drawer and an other which can be list or description

You can manage these different layouts with the [resources](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html), and FragmentManager to dynamically change list and description.

If you want only for tablets, the simple solution is to divide your view in 3 without fragment, but I do not advise this method because you will not be able to easily evolve your application

Answer (score 0):

One simple way is to use right and left drawers both!
Have a look at the below link.

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17861755/drawerlayout-double-drawer-left-and-right-drawers-simultaneously)